# Read file stream using JavaScript in web browser

Tags: html, stream, fileapi

In web browser, I want to compute sha1 checksum of a huge file in the local filesystem without sending it to a server.

[File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI) supports to read files from local disk but I guess it reads the entire of the file and put all of them into the memory. It may occur a problem if the file is larger than system memory.

[Streams API](http://www.w3.org/TR/streams-api) seems to be useful to solve this problem but I couldn't find how to read a file using the API.

Is there any way to read file stream from local disk using javascript in web browser?

Comment: hmm. XMLHttpRequest seems to be able to open a blob url from URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'd like to know the same.

Comment: @monkeymatrix Not yet. I think the APIs should be improved to solve this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The file api provides a slice method, so you should be able to read chunks of data

```
var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endindByte);
```

The Sha1 class in google's crypto api provides a update method, you should be able to feed the update method with your chunks

source:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.crypt.Sha1.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works very well and I write an example here: https://gist.github.com/npcode/11282867

Comment: @npcode Thanks for the link - but the link is now dead?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Yeah, you're right. Here is the new link: https://gist.github.com/eungjun-yi/11282867

Comment: Great that it works, but you chunk the file manually with a loop.  Isn't the whole point of Streams that you don't have to do this annoying chunking yourself?

Comment: @Phil You're right, it would be better to you FileReader.onload, it already reads chunks.