# How to calculate the sha1 hash of large files with javascript in the browser without creating memory overload

Tags: javascript, sha1

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the hash of large files in javascript without having to load the whole file in a FileReader. Is there a way to calculate the sha1 of a file by streaming it in javascript?

I'm looking at [sha.js](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/sha.js) but I'm not sure how it could be done in JavaScript client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been answered here: [Read file stream using javascript in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586839/read-file-stream-using-javascript-in-web-browser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The File API has a slice method that lets you read a file in parts.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice

For more information on how this can be done:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Google's implementation of SHA1 here:

https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/crypt/sha1.js